# Can I share Steam updates between computers?

Tags: steam

I've got two computers in my home network, both with Steam installed. If there's an update to Steam itself or the kids install a game it has to be downloaded to both. At the moment this happens twice, once for each computer.

Is there something I can do either within Steam or externally so that only one download happens and Steam picks up the local copy, thus saving my bandwidth?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In my own experience you can simple copy paste the entire Steam/Valve folder and run it from it's new destination.

Hence, yes you can just copy the entire game's folder with the updates to the other computer

And I just stumbled upon a Super User question about this. [Quoting John T:](https://superuser.com/questions/16943/move-steam-games-to-new-computer/16947#16947)

> I do this all the time it is fine to
>   do. Any files that do not match are
>   usually re-downloaded from Steam,
>   hence why it will still update a bit
>   after a fresh copy. If you do not want
>   all the sounds and maps which take up
>   a lot of space, you can simply take
>   the .gcf files for each game from
>   Program Files/Steam/SteamApps, these
>   are the biggest files in the update
>   which will save the most time.
>
> Steam also has a "Backup" feature you
>   can use. The files it creates can be
>   moved from PC to PC and restored on
>   any one.

Comment: I can confirm this works as well. I've done it between my own pcs as well as to/from friend's pcs.

Comment: The same works for World of Warcraft, saves A LOT of downloading!

Comment: Ha - so as long as they mainly log into one computer to get the updates I can do the copy to the other later.

Comment: @Ivo - that Valve link just takes me to a general page.

Comment: Borrowed it from the Super User thread, but appears to be dead by now... Deleted it for now

Comment: I did the same thing when I installed on my new laptop. I had to update steam again but all my steam files and games copied over to the new computer.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to backup through steam on one machine and then restore the backup to the 2nd machine.